# What the error is too large with third order polynomial fitting?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In the following code I tried to use third order polynomial. But my fitting is not good. I'm wondering how to improve fitting? Is there anything wrong in the code that is not allowing good fitting?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def poly3d(L, a, b,c,d):
    return (a*L**3+b*L**2+c*L+d)

Lz= np.array([16, 18, 20, 22, 24])
K= np.array([1.72388485, 1.8776344, 2.09188997, 2.17352828, 2.2491747])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(1.0/Lz,K,marker='s', color='blue', s=8**2)
pfit, pcov = curve_fit(poly3d,Lz,K)
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
x_arr = np.linspace(16,24,100)
x=1/x_arr
plt.plot(x, poly3d(x_arr, *pfit), marker='.', color='red')
```

Comment: Is there anything unclear in this question?

Comment: Hi Joee, welcome to the community! Would you be able to provide more context for the question? I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, because the answers depends on what you want to fit.

Comment: Since you have 5 points, so 4 order polynomial will have perfect fit, and you will get error for lower order polynomials.